# JavaScript Problem with function with parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have a little problem with my function.
When I try to run my function with parameter, it fails. I tried:

- `function(a4)`
- `function('a4')`
- `function("a4")`

and nothing works :( I don't know where is my problem. I want to create a function because my code is repeating 10 times, so I would like to switch only a function parameter. Please, help!

This function works:

```
function zmien_dane() {                       
             const silnik = document.querySelector('#dane'); 
             var zawartosc = silnik.dataset.a4;
             document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = zawartosc;
             const spalanie = document.querySelector('#dane2');
             var zawartosc = spalanie.dataset.a4;
             document.getElementById("dane2").innerHTML = zawartosc;
             const skrzynia = document.querySelector('#dane3');
             var zawartosc = skrzynia.dataset.a4;
             document.getElementById("dane3").innerHTML = zawartosc;
             const nadwozie = document.querySelector('#dane4');
             var zawartosc = nadwozie.dataset.a4;
             document.getElementById("dane4").innerHTML = zawartosc;
}
```

This function doesn't work:

```
function zmien_dane(parameter) {                         
             const silnik = document.querySelector('#dane');
             var zawartosc = silnik.dataset.parameter;
             document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = zawartosc;
             const spalanie = document.querySelector('#dane2');
             var zawartosc = spalanie.dataset.parameter;
             document.getElementById("dane2").innerHTML = zawartosc;
             const skrzynia = document.querySelector('#dane3');
             var zawartosc = skrzynia.dataset.parameter;
             document.getElementById("dane3").innerHTML = zawartosc;
             const nadwozie = document.querySelector('#dane4');
             var zawartosc = nadwozie.dataset.parameter;
             document.getElementById("dane4").innerHTML = zawartosc;
}
```

Comment: Try [`silnik.dataset[parameter]` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use square bracket like this

```
silnik.dataset[parameter];
```

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Syntax)